# What is the difference between pandas "describe" and "describe()"?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When I am calling the function describe without round brackets in my jupyter notebook the results are different, however I would expect an error message for the call without the bracket.
When searching I only found articles about `describe()`, but nothing about `describe`. I feel like a fool for asking this, because I am sure this is simple but I don't understand yet.

The code looks like this:

```
file_path = '../input/data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
data.describe #instead of data.describe()
```

The two results look like this:

**describe()**:
[image: describe() result]

**describe**:
[image: describe]

Comment: The key is `bound method NDFrame.describe of` in the output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.describe` is the bound method. It's bound to your dataframe, and the *representation* of a bound method includes the `repr()` output of whatever it is bound to.

You can see this at the start of the output:

```
<bound method NDFrame.describe of ...>
```

The *rest* is just the same string as what `repr(data)` produces.

Note that Python interactive interpreter always echoes the representation of whatever the last expression produced (unless it produced `None`). `data.describe` produces the bound method, `data.describe()` produces whatever that method was designed to produce.

You can create the same kind of output for *any* bound method:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "[This is an instance of the Foo class]"
...     def bar(self):
...         return "This is what Foo().bar() produces"
...
>>> Foo()
[This is an instance of the Foo class]
>>> Foo().bar
<bound method Foo.bar of [This is an instance of the Foo class]>
>>> Foo().bar()
"This is what Foo().bar() produces"
```

Note that `Foo()` has a custom `__repr__` method, which is what is called to produce the representation of an instance.

You can see the same kind of output (the representation of the whole dataframe) for any method on the dataframe you don't actually *call*, e.g. `data.sum`, `data.query`, `data.pivot`, or `data.__repr__`.

A bound method is part of the process by which Python passes in the instance as the first argument when you call it, the argument usually named `self`. It is basically a proxy object with references to the original function (`data.describe.__func__`) and the instance to pass in before all other arguments (`data.describe.__self__`). See the [descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for details on how binding works.

If you wanted to express the `__repr__` implementation of a bound method as Python code, it would be:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f"<bound method {self.__func__.__qualname__} of {self.__self__!r}>"
```

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of over-simplifying:
`.describe` is a method which is part of the `NDFrame` class, which can be called to get stats on your frame.

You **use** this method by calling the `describe()` function.

For more detail, and an excellent low-level explanation - see [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60677270/6340496).

Answer (score 1):

The output tells you what's happening, but it takes some decoding. When you call `df.describe`, you get

`bound method NDFrame.describe of <your dataframe`

In other words,it's returning the description of the `describe` method, which is `bound` to your dataframe object

Though not exactly analogous since it's not bound to an object, it's similar to the following case, where we define a function that operates on the `__main__` namespace, then call it both with and without parentheses

```
def myfunc():
    return "hello world"

myfunc()

'hello world'

myfunc #no parentheses

<function __main__.myfunc()>
```

Note the second case, where it tells us it's a function, its name is `myfunc`, and it's "bound" to the `__main__` namespace rather than to an object (not exactly, but close enough)

Comment: So that description (of the dataframe object) is not related to its content?

Comment: It is a method _of_ that dataframe, and as you've seen, it is tied to that dataframe, But, it's essentially just telling you the name of the function `df.describe()` and telling you which object it is assigned to. The `repr` as another answer explained.